# Windows spooler API GetPrinter() is not returning struct PRINTER_INFO_6 properly filled

Tags: c, windows, winapi, printing

I'm using [Printer Spooling API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/printdocs/printing-and-print-spooler-functions) to retrive the printer status information [`PRINTER_INFO_6`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/printdocs/printer-info-6) using [`GetPrinter()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/printdocs/getprinter) function.

My goal is to determine paper status (`PRINTER_STATUS_PAPER_JAM`, `PRINTER_STATUS_PAPER_OUT`, `PRINTER_STATUS_PAPER_PROBLEM`) and toner status (`PRINTER_STATUS_TONER_LOW`, `PRINTER_STATUS_NO_TONER`).

Strangely, regardless of printer state, `dwStatus` member is always zero.

The following code retrieves the printer status information from the default printer and displays it on the screen:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>


int main( void )
{
    HANDLE hPrinter = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    PPRINTER_INFO_6 pInfo = NULL;
    DWORD dwNeeded = 0L;
    CHAR szPrinterName[ MAX_PATH + 1 ] = {0};
    DWORD dwLength = MAX_PATH;
    BOOL ret = FALSE;


    ret = GetDefaultPrinter( szPrinterName, &dwLength );

    if( ret == FALSE )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "[FATAL] GetDefaultPrinter() failed: %lu\n", GetLastError() );
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    ret = OpenPrinter( szPrinterName, &hPrinter, NULL );

    if( ret == FALSE )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "[FATAL] OpenPrinter( '%s' ) failed: %lu\n", szPrinterName, GetLastError() );
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    GetPrinter( hPrinter, 6, NULL, 0, &dwNeeded );

    if(!dwNeeded)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "[FATAL] GetPrinter() failed: %lu\n", GetLastError() );
        ClosePrinter( hPrinter );
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    pInfo = (PRINTER_INFO_6*) HeapAlloc( GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, dwNeeded );

    if( pInfo == NULL )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "[FATAL] HeapAlloc() failed: %lu\n", GetLastError() );
        ClosePrinter( hPrinter );
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    ret = GetPrinter( hPrinter, 6, (LPBYTE) pInfo, dwNeeded, &dwNeeded );

    if( ret == FALSE )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "[FATAL] GetPrinter() failed: %lu\n", GetLastError() );
        HeapFree( GetProcessHeap(), 0, pInfo );
        ClosePrinter( hPrinter );
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fprintf( stdout, "pInfo->dwStatus: 0x%08lX\n", pInfo->dwStatus );

    HeapFree( GetProcessHeap(), 0, pInfo );
    ClosePrinter( hPrinter );
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In the code above, `pInfo->dwStatus` is **always** `0x00000000`.

Could someone tell me what's wrong? Clues?

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41437023/trying-to-determine-printer-status-always-returns-0-for-offline-online-printer/41483350 relevant? (i.e. are you trying to determine online/offline status?)

Comment: Those HeapFree calls are somewhat pointless. Also, why do you ignore return value of GetPrinter? The documentation is pretty clear on that matter.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I'm trying to determine toner and paper status (`PRINTER_STATUS_PAPER_OUT` and `PRINTER_STATUS_NO_TONER`). I'm ignoring the value returned by `GetPrinter()` function because it is calculating the size of the buffer needed to store `PRINTER_INFO_6` data. (will always fail in this case).

Comment: See [How to get the status of a printer and a print job](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/160129/how-to-get-the-status-of-a-printer-and-a-print-job). It sounds like you have to check both the printer (as you are doing) and the job queue as well.

Comment: If you try to use `PRINTER_INFO_2` instead of `PRINTER_INFO_6`. Is the value of `PRINTER_INFO_2.Status` also 0 always?

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT: same results, zero always!

Comment: What printer driver is being used? What printer port?  Also, if you remove all the paper, do you get the right status?

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT: regardless of printer state (tonner and paper completely removed) the status stills the same. I'm using an USB port. Same bahaviour when using a `PRINTER_INFO_2` structure. The [driver](http://support.lexmark.com/index?docLocale=en_US&page=content&segType=recommendedSegmentOS&id=DR23661&locale=EN&userlocale=EN_US). The printer is a Lexmark MS610dn on a windows 7 64-bit machine.

Comment: Hi,@Lacobus,1. To see the status of the printer, you must be doing something with the printer.  For example, you attempt to print.  At this point you can check on the status.  If the printer isn’t doing anything, the status will be zero.
2. A better way to know what the printer is doing is for the application to register for notifications.

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is to determine paper status (`PRINTER_STATUS_PAPER_JAM`,
>   `PRINTER_STATUS_PAPER_OUT`, `PRINTER_STATUS_PAPER_PROBLEM`) and toner
>   status (`PRINTER_STATUS_TONER_LOW`, `PRINTER_STATUS_NO_TONER`).

Print status is changed to the above value only when the printer has the issue above. `Status = 0` means that the printer is currently idle/ready. If you Google the keyword "Printer Status Codes", you will see Status Code = 0 means Printer ready. Seem that it hasn't been documented, or defined as a macro.

Paper and toner issue status is like "runtime status", if you do not start to print, then no such issue status code will be set. For example,
You have to call `GetLastError()` after an api but not before.